# Cannot output contents of list in OOP

Tags: python, oop

My list in Python outputs an object type like this:
`[<user_action_oop.Trial object at 0x7f65ebe14550>, <user_action_oop.Trial object at 0x7f65ebf9da90>]`
I am trying to utilize an OOP function.

How do I output the real contents of the list?
Thank you.

```
class Trial:
    def __init__(self):
        self.listahan = []
        self.user_input = input("Type 'a' to add item to list\n's' to view your list\n'e' to edit your list\n'x' to "
                        "exit and view your list\n'r' to remove item from the list\n").strip().lower()

    def add_to_list(self):
        self.item = input('Type in an item\n')
        self.listahan.append(self.item)
        print(self.listahan)

    def print_the_list(self):
        print(self.listahan)
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code that you have tried with, then we can help you troubleshoot any issues you might have with that. To learn more about how the [SO] community can help you, please take the [tour] and read [ask].